# Paypal error Received an unexpected EOF or 0 bytes from the transport stream in Asp.net

Tags: c#, asp.net, paypal, paypal-sandbox

I'm getting this error, Received an unexpected EOF or 0 bytes from the transport stream, when calling SetExpressCheckout in api-3t.sandbox.paypal.com. I'm using Asp.net to call the api.

Here is my code:

```
private static NameValueCollection Submit(string values)
{
    HttpWebRequest request = (HttpWebRequest)WebRequest.Create(
       String.Format("https://{0}/nvp", PayPalSettings.ApiDomain));

    request.Method = "POST";
    request.ContentLength = values.Length;

    using (StreamWriter writer = new StreamWriter(request.GetRequestStream()))
    {
        writer.Write(values);
    }

    WebResponse webResponse = request.GetResponse();
    Stream response = webResponse.GetResponseStream();
    using (StreamReader reader = new StreamReader(response))
    {
        return HttpUtility.ParseQueryString(reader.ReadToEnd());
    }
}
```

The error would occur when I call request.GetRequestStream().

The **values** parameter contains:
USER=< username >&PWD=< password >&METHOD=SetExpressCheckout&VERSION=76.0&HDRIMG=< image url >&RETURNURL=< return url >&CANCELURL=< cancel url >&BUTTONSOURCE=PP-ECWizard&SUBJECT=&ALLOWNOTE=0&PAYMENTREQUEST_0_PAYMENTACTION=Sale&PAYMENTREQUEST_0_AMT=100&PAYMENTREQUEST_0_CURRENCYCODE=AUD&NOSHIPPING=1&L_PAYMENTREQUEST_0_NAME0=Registration&L_PAYMENTREQUEST_0_DESC0=Registration+Details&L_PAYMENTREQUEST_0_QTY0=1&L_PAYMENTREQUEST_0_AMT0=100

**PayPalSettings.ApiDomain** = api-3t.sandbox.paypal.com

What's weird is that if I use the same code above and call the live/production paypal api it will work. Using the live/production url and credentials of course.

Also if I post the url mentioned above(*https://api-3t.sandbox.paypal.com/nvp?USER=< username >&PWD=< password >&METHOD=SetExpressCheckout&VERSION=76.0&HDRIMG=< image url >&RETURNURL=< return url >&CANCELURL=< cancel url >&BUTTONSOURCE=PP-ECWizard&SUBJECT=&ALLOWNOTE=0&PAYMENTREQUEST_0_PAYMENTACTION=Sale&PAYMENTREQUEST_0_AMT=100&PAYMENTREQUEST_0_CURRENCYCODE=AUD&NOSHIPPING=1&L_PAYMENTREQUEST_0_NAME0=Registration&L_PAYMENTREQUEST_0_DESC0=Registration+Details&L_PAYMENTREQUEST_0_QTY0=1&L_PAYMENTREQUEST_0_AMT0=100*) in a browser it would return the desired result.

Your help would be greatly appreciated.

Thank you.

Comment: You may need to check your environment, Paypal enhance security in sandbox environment recently. Refer to https://www.paypal-knowledge.com/infocenter/index?page=content&id=FAQ1913

Comment: @ZhaoSamanta - Thank you for the information you shared. But one thing though, if PayPal enhanced the security for sandbox environment shouldn't they do the same enhancements to their live environment as well. As I was reading through the PayPal API documentation they suggest that when developing use sandbox environment and when done just shift to live environment. Currently my web app works in live environment. Also when I post the URL(for sandbox) directly to a browser it also works. Would appreciate any help you or anyone can give. Thanks.

Comment: PayPal make the change in sandbox environment firstly to let merchant aware of the change. Live environment will be changed later, maybe at June this year.

Answer (score 3):

After some research I figured out.
Apparently since some months ago `paypal` change the TLS version supported making version 1.2 the minimum supported.

The problem is that .Net Framework 3.5 does not support that version.
For frameworks higher than 3.5 you can add the next line:

```
ServicePointManager.SecurityProtocol = (SecurityProtocolType)3072;
```

Since this problem is almost from a year ago, I dont think Microsoft is going to make an update for fw 3.5, so I suggest to migrate your App to 4.5.

Comment: VB version: System.Net.ServicePointManager.SecurityProtocol = System.Net.SecurityProtocolType.Tls12